# ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in console but the app works correctly

Tags: javascript

In my app I get error message in console

`GET chrome-extension://lncjpblllfcpljbdelleomhnlgdlhhmm/content/styles.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

after every new request, but in the same time I do not see any other issues and application seems to be running correctly. Currently I cannot look up any line in my code files where the `styles.css` file is mentioned (only `App.css` and `all.css`).
Why cannot this file be found and how can I fix it?

Here is an HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title>Welcome to DevConnector!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Disable all Chrome extensions

Comment: That's an error for an extension you have installed, not your app